# Finding acceleration of center of mass in cart pole problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, vectors

In [this link](http://coneural.org/florian/papers/05_cart_pole.pdf) about finding equations of motion of cart pole problem,
There is an equation about acceleration of center of mass of the pole.
Screenshots of them below.

[image]

[image]

I don't understand why they have more than two parts about angular acceleration - $\varepsilon \times r_p$ and $\omega \times (\omega \times r_p)$?

If I'm being right, first one is torque, and second one is acceleration of a point in circular movement.

I guess in some part I'm being incorrect, but I don't understand why they put two angular acceleration of it? It's copy of them, aren't they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you transfer velocity from one point to another in a rigid body you end up with an equation like

$$ \boldsymbol{v}_P = \boldsymbol{v}_C + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{r}_P $$

Acceleration is just the time derivative of the above with

$$ \begin{aligned}
 \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \boldsymbol{v}_P &= \boldsymbol{a}_P \\
 \tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}\boldsymbol{v}_C & = \boldsymbol{a}_C \\
\tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \boldsymbol{\omega} &= \boldsymbol{\epsilon} \\
\tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \boldsymbol{r}_P &= \boldsymbol{\omega} \times \boldsymbol{r}_P
\end{aligned} $$

<sub>The last part is because $\boldsymbol{r}_P$ is a fixed vector riding along with the rigid body.</sub>

The transformation of acceleration is thus

$$ \boldsymbol{a}_P = \boldsymbol{a}_C + (\tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t}\boldsymbol{\omega} )\times \boldsymbol{r}_P  + \boldsymbol{\omega} \times (\tfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}t} \boldsymbol{r}_P) $$

$$\boldsymbol{a}_P = \boldsymbol{a}_C + \boldsymbol{\epsilon} \times \boldsymbol{r}_P + \boldsymbol{\omega}  \times ( \boldsymbol{\omega}  \times \boldsymbol{r}_P) $$

Answer (score 0):

That last term is the centripetal acceleration associated with the rotation of the rod.